# Running private docker registry v2 on AWS ECS with SSL and basic auth

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to set up a private docker registry on ECS (following the guide http://www.elastic.io/en/running-a-docker-private-registry-on-ec2/), with an ELB in front, terminating SSL with a self signed certificate. The registry itself is running and registered with the ELB, and after updating the OS ca-cert bundle and the docker host folder with the CA for the self signed certificate, I can successfully run `curl -u myuser:mypass https://myawselb.domain/v2/`, and I can successfully do `docker login myawselb.domain`, but doing `docker push myawselb.domain/my-image` always fails, no matter what... I have tried all combinations of repository ids with and without ports and https prefix, but all requests fail. This is logged in the docker log:

```
time="2015-10-20T20:05:12.197307689Z" level=debug msg="Calling POST /images/{name:.*}/push" 
time="2015-10-20T20:05:12.197370508Z" level=info msg="POST /v1.20/images/myawselb.domain/myimage/push?tag="
time="2015-10-20T20:05:32.439207664Z" level=debug msg="hostDir: /etc/docker/certs.d/myawselb.domain" 
time="2015-10-20T20:05:42.630367623Z" level=debug msg="hostDir: /etc/docker/certs.d/myawselb.domain" 
time="2015-10-20T20:05:42.630665342Z" level=debug msg="Trying to push myawselb.domain/my-image to https://myawselb.domain v2" 
time="2015-10-20T20:05:47.635771226Z" level=debug msg="Error getting v2 registry: Get https://myawselb.domain/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection" 
time="2015-10-20T20:05:47.635965903Z" level=debug msg="Trying to push myawselb.domain/my-image to https://myawselb.domain v1"
```

Then after some more push attempts it fails with a 404 page not found.

The registry server logs:

```
time="2015-10-20T20:26:09Z" level=warning msg="error authorizing context: basic authentication challenge: htpasswd.challenge{realm:\"my auth realm\", err:(*errors.errorString)(0xc2080792d0)}" http.request.host=myawselb.domain http.request.id=510894a1-2db5-4782-98da-d9fefc6b13cc http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr=myip http.request.uri="/v2/" http.request.useragent="docker/1.8.3 go/go1.4.2 git-commit/f4bf5c7 kernel/4.1.10-boot2docker os/linux arch/amd64" instance.id=my-instance-id version=v2.1.1 
10.0.0.x - - [20/Oct/2015:20:26:09 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 401 114 "" "docker/1.8.3 go/go1.4.2 git-commit/f4bf5c7 kernel/4.1.10-boot2docker os/linux arch/amd64"
10.0.0.y - - [20/Oct/2015:20:26:19 +0000] "PUT /v1/repositories/my-image/ HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "" "docker/1.8.3 go/go1.4.2 git-commit/f4bf5c7 kernel/4.1.10-boot2docker os/linux arch/amd64"
```

I might have forgotten something obvious, but I'm starting to run out of ideas. So any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your docker daemon can't conenct via HTTP to the `myawselb.domain` are you sure it's resolvable from the host where your docker daemon is running?

Another thing to check is wherever the local docker version is one of the latest, we had some issues with older docker daemons before.

Renat

Comment: It's not (at least not an obvious) connection problem. I can connect using `curl`. I just upgraded to latest Docker Toolbox (OS X), but still the same issue. However, I installed Docker Toolbox on a windows computer, and it works there. So I guess either I need to re-create the boot2docker image and see if it is fixed with a "plain" Docker Toolbox, or it's a bug with Docker Toolbox/Boot2Docker on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, removing the nameserver `8.8.8.8` from `/etc/resolv.conf` in the docker vm solved the issue. I have no idea why that should make any difference, but it did.